# node-pre-gyp err completion callback never invoked

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, grpc, marble

I met this error when installed the IBM's blockchain demo marbles.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJdsv.png)

it seems a bug of grpc, but i can not find d solution to solve it.

Comment: This looks like [this node-pre-gyp issue](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/367), which unfortunately has not yet been solved.

Answer (score 1):

This was a [bug in node-pre-gyp](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/367), which gRPC uses. That bug has been fixed, and gRPC version 1.13.1 has been published with the fixed version of node-pre-gyp bundled.